Ignition Gazebo - Physics
Can someone help me understand how to add RayTrace to a system plugin?
I was reading through the documentation on the same at
physics
Can someone help me understand how to add RayTrace to a system plugin?
I was reading through the documentation on the same at
physics
From what I understood we need to implement the same as a custom feature as stated in this tutorial.Custom Feature
But I do not need the implementation to be a plugin, instead I need to use the Raytrace in another system plugin.
Any help or hints on this will be appreciated. Thank you.
